# Step-down transformer energy efficiency

Tags: power, transformer, efficiency

I moved from the US to the UK and I need to use a step-down transformer for my PC and monitor. It was recommended that I use three times the power that PC and monitor consume to account for power surges.

The question here is that if I use a 1500 W step-down for a 500 W monitor, will my power consumption be three times higher throughout the usage? Is it more energy efficient for me to trash my PC and buy a UK compliant one?

Comment: That three times recommendation does not sound correct to me. But I would not trash the PC...just replace the power supply in the PC. Better yet, it probably has a on the back switch on it to change it to 120V.

Comment: Many computers and other electronics have universal power supplies, and can accept 100 - 240V mains inputs.  Check the labels on your computer and monitor - you may not need any transformer.

Comment: Some really cheap PC power supplies need you to flip a switch. That used to be normal, but more modern ones Just Work on either voltage. But yes, check the label first - don't assume, or it might go bang.

Answer (score 4):

If you connect a 500 watt load to a transformer rated to handle 1500 watts, the transformer will only draw a little more than 500 watts.

Theoretically, the power in to the transformer should equal the power out, but there will be some small power loss within the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy a new SMPS in UK for your US purchased PC. Usually, some SMPS work at different voltage ratings. For the monitor, perhaps you can just buy a 220V to 110V adapter. Maybe the 220V to 110V down voltage converter is not really efficient but you have to make a compromise if you want to use existing hardware.

Comment: I dont know UK power outlet rating. I am assuming it is 220V-240V. The universal power adapters seem to have 6A limit.  Perhaps the PC and the monitor consume more current.

Comment: By universal power I mean that the PC and monitor *probably* support 100-240 V input.

Comment: Yes the universal power adapter can support both PC and monitor with a extension cord but its total current limit is around 6A. This may vary in different adapters.

Comment: I'm NOT talking about any adapter, the PC and monitor can probably run on 240 V just fine.  Most likely OP does not need any adapter, but if they do they already have one.  See the comments under the question.

Comment: Oh, I misread the question, they don't already have the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Great tips everyone ! I finally figured out that both monitor and PC use 100-240V. So was able to just use an adapter. My printer is 110v only. So cheaper to just replace it.